# Get all the duplicates record in a csv if a column is different

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a csv file, which have column wise data, like

```
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,15920221,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488676,11014018,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488700,7273867,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23486360,7273881,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,7273807,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,9738420,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,7273845,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488676,12149463,ESTIMATED
```

and i just want to find out all the duplicates row ignoring a column, which is column 3. the output should be like

```
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,15920221,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488676,11014018,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488700,7273867,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,7273807,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,9738420,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488670,7273845,ESTIMATED
EvtsUpdated,IR23488676,12149463,ESTIMATED
```

i tried it by first cutting other columns except 3 in another file using

```
cut --complement -f 3 -d, filename into another file,
```

then i tried using the awk command, like awk -F, '{if(FNR==NR){print}}' secondfile

As i don't have complete knowledge of awk, so i'm not able to do it

Comment: take a look at [comm](https://ss64.com/bash/comm.html) "Common - compare two sorted files line by line and write to standard output: 
the lines that are common, plus the lines that are unique."

Comment: can't solve from the comm comand

Comment: @ggupta `EvtsUpdated,IR23488700,7273867,ESTIMATED` is not duplicate . why is it still part of the output?

Comment: What is **column 3** Do you mean it with zero-index or not?

Comment: @k-five not, with 0 index, in above data it is second last column

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk arrays to store the count of each group of columns to identify duplicates.

```
awk -F "," '{row[$1$2$4]++ ; rec[$0","NR] = $1$2$4 }
END{ for ( key in rec ) { if (row[rec[key]] > 1) { print key }   } }' filename | sort -t',' -k5 | cut -f1-4 -d','
```

An additional `sort` was required to maintain the original ordering expected in your output.

**Note**: In your output shown, row with `IR23488700` is considered as duplicate even though it is not.

Comment: i have given sample of data, they may be multiple columns so taking column wise will be more difficult i think.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same by first cutting the 3rd column which may be different and then running the `awk '++A[$0]==2' file` command. Thanks for your help